# change background color document with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the following code :

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function change(color) {
            document.bgColor = color;
        }

    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="green">
            <div id="slatenav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="WebForm3.aspx" id="green" onclick="change('green')">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WebForm4.aspx"  id="red" onclick="change('red')">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why it isn't working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you shouldn't be using `document.bgColor`, it should still work.  The problem isn't that -- but rather that you're using it with links which are cancelling the javascript (the link is loading a new page).

Give this a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function change(color) {
     document.bgColor = color;
     return false;
     }
</script>
<div id="slatenav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="WebForm3.aspx" id="green" onclick="return change('green');">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="WebForm4.aspx"  id="red" onclick="return change('red');">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuJ7t/)

It won't load the new page, but the `Javascript` will fire off.  And as others have suggested, use `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @user1799345 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

The **document.bgColor** is deprecated use **document.body.style.backgroundColor** instead

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.bgColor